# Choirs singing flat

Tags: pitch, choir

I heard from the conductor of a choir that if the choir sing music in G major they are more likely to go flat than if they sing in G flat major. Why should this be the case?

Comment: Because G is slightly higher?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why choirs consistently go flat or sharp in certain keys](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/243/why-choirs-consistently-go-flat-or-sharp-in-certain-keys)

Comment: Singing in a certain key means nothing. The tessitura and  range of the song bear far more importance to the issue. I'd be questioning the choirmaster much further.